# Is there a way I can create a random number that spawns a heart?

Tags: java, android-studio, random, while-loop

I have created code for a game that spawns a heart as an extra life continuously, however, I only want it to have a chance of happening sometimes, I have decided the best approach would be to generate a random number and if the number exceeds a certain value it will spawn a heart.

```
random = new Random();

    double randHeartNum = random.nextDouble();

    while (isPlaying == true) {

        if (randHeartNum < 0.050) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                Bird heart = new Bird(getResources());
                hearts[i] = heart;
            }
            randHeartNum = new Random().nextDouble();
        }
    }
```

the for loop spawns in the heart successfully but when it is surrounded by my random number generator it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

### What happened:

In the statement `randHeartNum = new Random().nextDouble();` a new Random() instance is being created, used and deleted for every loop iteration.

According to JavaDocs,

> `public Random()` Creates a new random number generator. This constructor sets the seed of the random number generator to a value very likely to be distinct from any other invocation of this constructor.

Repeatedly spamming the constructor and invoking the `nextDouble()` method provides values that are not uniformly distributed.

### What could be done:

```
random = new Random();

    double randHeartNum = random.nextDouble();

    while (isPlaying == true) {

        if (randHeartNum < 0.050) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                Bird heart = new Bird(getResources());
                hearts[i] = heart;
            }
            randHeartNum = random().nextDouble();
        }
    }
```

---

***Or***

Using `Math.random()` might be simpler -

```
    double randHeartNum;

    while (isPlaying == true) {

        randHeartNum = Math.random();

        if (randHeartNum < 0.050) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                Bird heart = new Bird(getResources());
                hearts[i] = heart;
            }
        }
    }
```

### To know more:

[Math.random()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--)

[java.util.Random()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)